# Overriding the Magento customer controller to have custom form actions

Tags: forms, magento, overriding, controllers, magento-1.8

I've created a new template for my Homepage with only a registration and a login form. So far, the actions on both these forms were the default actions that I called like this:
`echo Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterPostUrl()` for the registration form and
`echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginPostUrl()` for the login form.

I am now trying to override the  Customer controller to change the action of these forms. So far I have: 
a. Created a new module and edited the `app/code/local/MyCo/Homepage/etc/config.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyCo_Homepage>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyCo_Homepage>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <myco_homepage before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">MyCo_Homepage</myco_homepage>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

b. Created a controller in the file `app/code/local/MyCo/Homepage/controllers/IndexController.php` and extended it from `Mage_Customer_AccountController` like this:

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Bemaad_Homepage_IndexController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
  public function loginPostAction()
  {
  }

  public function createPostAction()
  {
  }
}
```

My problem is: I don't know what to put in the action attributes of the form and Magento doesn't seem to register my new controller.

Does anyone know where I've made a mistake, or did I forget something?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, the predispath  function create the issue  http://goo.gl/bXGmzr

Comment: Except I don't want to use any dispatch function, I want to override these two functions.

Comment: Question is not clear.please explain...

Comment: what do u mean by "I've created a new template for my Homepage with only a registration and a login form"... Does ur home page itself have the login form and registration forms???

Comment: @PavanKumar Yes, This is a new page that only have the login and registration forms.

Comment: Did you check this link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-login-form-on-home-page-in-magento/

Answer (score -1):

Your config should be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyCo_Homepage>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyCo_Homepage>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <customer>
        <modules>
          <myco_homepage before="Mage_Customer">MyCo_Homepage</myco_homepage>
        </modules>
      </customer>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Additionally your overloading controller class must have the same controller name as the overloaded one.

So Instead of **Bemaad_Homepage_IndexController** it should be **Bemaad_Homepage_AccountController**

See here for reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Comment: I've made the changes, however do you know what are the actions I should put on the forms?

Comment: You can use the original actions (URLs), you just have to override the corresponding action methods in your overriding controller.

Comment: I tried overriding the function `_loginPostRedirect()` that is called after the login and it didn't redirect to the correct page...

Comment: Try to override `loginPostAction()` first to check if your controller override is active. If not, clear magento config cache and check again.

Comment: I have overridden `loginPostAction()` but it still doesn't redirects to the correct page.

Comment: The question was how to override a controller. Is your own child controller now active or not? Is your own `loginPostAction` method being called actually or not?

If you are successful with this then the question has been answered.

Which steps you take now inside your overriden action and where to redirect after the action is ready is an another topic.

Comment: Well then the `loginPostAction` method is not called and the child controller is not active. So the question hasn't been answered.